# How to add progress dialog in okhttp3 out of listener in android

Tags: android, okhttp

This is my `MainActivity` file. I am trying to select an `Image` file from external storage and upload it to server with percentage progress.
I want to add `ProgressDialog` to it , i attempted to add but it **throwing run time error**.

```
package com.example.panchayat.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.Manifest;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.MultipartBody;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import com.example.panchayat.myapplication.CountingFileRequestBody;
import com.example.panchayat.myapplication.CountingFileRequestBody.ProgressListener;
import com.example.panchayat.myapplication.ProgressRequestBody.Listener;
import com.example.panchayat.myapplication.ProgressRequestBody;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, 1);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1: {

                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // contacts-related task you need to do.
                } else {
                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission denied to read your External storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //finishAffinity();
                    //System.exit(0);
                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == this.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            return;
        }
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (data != null) {
                Uri uri = data.getData();

                File myFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(uri));
                final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_PNG = MediaType.parse("image/png");
                RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                        .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                        .addFormDataPart("title", "Square Logo")
                        .addFormDataPart("image", "logo-square.png", RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG, myFile))
                        .build();

                //CountingFileRequestBody ok = new CountingFileRequestBody(requestBody, "image/jpg",progressListener);
                ProgressRequestBody ioo = new ProgressRequestBody(requestBody,progressListener);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, myFile.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url("http://bmi.ir/multi.php")
                        .post(ioo)
                        .build();

                client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

                                Log.d("ok",e.getMessage());
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                                Log.d("ok",response.body().string());
                                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response.body().string(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                );
            }
        }
    }
    final Listener progressListener = new Listener() {
        @Override public void onProgress(int bytesRead) {
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            final String myString = Long.toString(bytesRead);
            final int per = bytesRead;
            Log.d("ok", myString);
        }
    };

    private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI)
    {
        String result = null;

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor == null)
        { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
            result = contentURI.getPath();
        }
        else
        {
            if(cursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
                result = cursor.getString(idx);
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

How to get the progress % from the listener and update the `ProgressDialog`?

Comment: can you post your error?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onProgress(int bytesRead) {
    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    double percentage = 100 * bytesRead/fileLength;
    Log.d(TAG,"Progress percentage: " + percentage);
}
```

Comment: i needed to add progress dialog,  onProgress already getting percentage no need to add ``double percentage = 100 * bytesRead/fileLength;
``